# Dropdown list not showing, Bootstrap and Google apps scripts, Dropdown populates from spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, dropdown, spreadsheet, bootstrap-5

I've been trying to make this work for hours, it seems like everything is in order but I cant make it work

Hopefully, maybe someone can point me in the right direction, do you see any issues with this code?

The relevant part is the last function on the first file

and for the second file, all just after the form components

I'm desperate :(

This is the code I'm using

code.gs

```
  function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Webappboot");                                                                 //Name of the HTML file
  }

  function AddRecord(input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6, input7) {                                               //Names of the componentsIDs
    
    var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById("1JJrWaeiDUC7TKFo3zjG3MHWJ90OnU6N3AiEh-9cXdaE");                                         //Paste Google Sheet ID
    var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TrainingLogData");                                                                  //Paste Data Sheet Name
    var lastRow = webAppSheet.getLastRow();


    webAppSheet.insertRows(2, 1);//shift all rows down by one from row 2
    
    webAppSheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(lastRow);                                                  //Entry ID
    webAppSheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(input1);                                                   // Date
    webAppSheet.getRange(2,3).setFormula('="Wk - " & WEEKNUM(B2) & " - " & YEAR(B2)');            // Week # and Year Formula: ="Wk - " & WEEKNUM(B2) & " - " & YEAR(B2)
    webAppSheet.getRange(2,4).setValue(input2);                                                   //Exercise
    webAppSheet.getRange(2,5).setValue(input3);                                                   //Mov.Pattern/Muscle Group
    webAppSheet.getRange(2,6).setValue(input4);                                                   //Sets
    webAppSheet.getRange(2,7).setValue(input5);                                                   //Reps
    webAppSheet.getRange(2,8).setValue(input6);                                                   //RIR
    webAppSheet.getRange(2,9).setValue(input7);                                                   //Kg                             
    webAppSheet.getRange(2,10).setValue(new Date());                                              //Timestamp


  } 

  function getDropDownArray (){
    var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1JJrWaeiDUC7TKFo3zjG3MHWJ90OnU6N3AiEh-9cXdaE");                                         //Google Sheet ID
    var dropdownSheet = ss2.getSheetByName("SupportSheet");                                                                    //Sheet with dropdown options
    var lastRowdd = dropdownSheet.getLastRow();

    return dropdownSheet.getRange(1,2,lastRowdd, 1).getValues();

  }
```

HTML

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <script>
      function AddRow()
      {
        var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
        var input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
        var input3 = document.getElementById("input3").value;
        var input4 = document.getElementById("input4").value;
        var input5 = document.getElementById("input5").value;
        var input6 = document.getElementById("input6").value;
        var input7 = document.getElementById("input7").value;
        if(input1 != '' && input2 != '' && input3 != '' && input4 != '' && input5 != '' && input6 != '' && input7 != '')
        {
        google.script.run.AddRecord(input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6, input7);
        document.getElementById("input1").value = '';
        document.getElementById("input2").value = '';
        document.getElementById("input3").value = '';
        document.getElementById("input4").value = '';
        document.getElementById("input5").value = '';
        document.getElementById("input6").value = '';
        document.getElementById("input7").value = '';
        document.getElementById("display_error").innerHTML = "";
        }
        else
        {
        document.getElementById("display_error").innerHTML = "Enter All Information";
        }
      }
      </script>
          
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Login Form -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <div class="card shadow">
            <div class="card-title text-center border-bottom">
              <h2 class="p-3">Data Entry</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <form>
                
                <div class="mb-4">
                  <label for="input1" class="form-label">Input1</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="input1" />
                </div>
                              
                <div class="mb-4">
                  <label for="input2" class="form-label">input2</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2" />
                </div>
                
                <div class="mb-4">
                  <label for="input3" class="form-label">input3</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="input3" >
                  </select>

                  
                </div>
                
                <div class=row>
                
                <div class="col mb-4">
                  <label for="input4" class="form-label">input4</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="input4" />
                </div>
                
                <div class="col mb-4">
                  <label for="input5" class="form-label">input5</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="input5" />
                </div>
                  
                </div>
                
                <div class=row>
                
                <div class="col mb-4">
                  <label for="input6" class="form-label">input6</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input6" />
                </div>
        
                <div class="col mb-4">
                  <label for="input7" class="form-label">input7</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input7" />
                </div>
                  
                </div>
                
                <div class="mb-4">
                  <input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-1" onclick="AddRow()" />
                  <div id="display_error" style="color: red" ></div>
                </div>
                              
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  <script>
    
  function afterPageLoads() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterDropDownArrayReturned).getDropDownArray();
    
  }

  function afterDropDownArrayReturned(arrayOfArrays){
    var dditem = document.getElementById("input3");

    arrayOfArrays.forEach(function(r){
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.textContent = r[0];
      dditem.appendChild(option);
    });
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMcontentLoaded",afterPageLoads);

  </script>


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that in your script, `DOMcontentLoaded` is required to be modified.

#### From:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMcontentLoaded",afterPageLoads);
```

#### To:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", afterPageLoads);
```

- In this modification, `DOMcontentLoaded` is modified to `DOMContentLoaded`.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that the script of Google Apps Script side and other Javascript work fine. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: OMFG Thank You! I can't believe it was just a letter, THANK YOU so much, I hope it didn't take much of your time, thanks thanks thanks!!!

Comment: @Rolroorlo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.